# Apache2 on Ubuntu - Start external process on request?

Tags: apache-2.2, scripting, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 14.04.01 LTS (i368). I would like to start an external process whenever a request comes in (The process started will actually get the request proxied to it.)

I am setting up a server to host whatever weekend projects I have. My plan for this is simpleish(tm) I have some configs that redirect the appropriate subdomain (ex. myproject.mydomain.com), to the appropriate subdir (ex. /var/www/projects/myproject). There my goal is to have a .htaccess file that will run a script (.sh file) whenever a request comes in. That script will start the server for the project (node, ruby, whatever), on an available port. The .htaccess then redirects (after maybe a 10s delay) to the server using reverse-proxying. The server then will automatically shut down after an hour of inactivity.

I can work out the script, my question is how to run it. I essentially need a way in my .htaccess to run the script, wait a few seconds, the proxy.

I am open to other solutions (php, etc), and Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could cron a bash task that check the apache log, and when a certain request got hit you trigger your task.

Comment: @yagmoth555, I don't think that will work, it would be too much delay.